# Is there a mechanism to ask for reopening a question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, flags, duplicate-questions

A question of mine was closed as a duplicate, and a question marked as duplicate states:

> This question was marked as an *exact duplicate* of an existing question

I'm pretty sure it hasn't been read by the person who flagged, because it's different from the one it is marked as a duplicate. At least is not **an exact duplicate** of an existing question.

The worst part is that I was the one who provided the answer he/she refers as duplicate, when I posted the question. I did it to show I made a research, and it wasn't the answer I was looking for, to prevent people who don't read the entire question, raise a duplicate flag (this is not the first time I see a question, which is not an exact duplicate marked as duplicate... often very interesting questions).

I know I have no high reputation, but I was never raised with bad flags or made inappropriate questions. Of course, I could make a question which is a duplicate, but not the ones I provide the link of that answer.

It was marked as duplicate by only one person, and of course it doesn't worth to reedit the question. No one review that. So, I think there should be a way to tell a committee to review a question marked as duplicate, which the person who asked think it is not an "exact duplicate".

I'm pretty sure now I'm going to be flagged because of this, but I think it isn't fair.
All questions I made, have a previous a research, I provide links about it, I explain what I tried and why it don't work or where I stuck. It's not fair that because **only one person** think it's a duplicate (no matter how high is his/her reputation), all that effort worth nothing. I'm really mad. I'm sorry.

Comment: Yeah, yeah...  I already posted that answer in my question too: re-edit the question. As I said that worth nothing. I never saw a question closed as a duplicate, reopened (often very good questions).

Comment: Having looked at the question you're talking about: if you have a follow-up question to an existing question, *do not title it almost identically to the original question.* That's going to get it closed as a duplicate and rightly so. Try to find a title, and an introduction, that acknowledges where you're coming from, and states clearly which aspect wasn't answered satisfactorily in the original question.

Comment: @Pekka웃, I know it is only my opinion, but the most important is the content of the answer, not the title. One should not close a question only because of the title, without reading its content. Thanks for point of view, i'll keep in mind.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets 10,000+ questions every day. If you give a question a generic title, it's likely to get closed as a duplicate, especially if you hide your *real* question at the end of the question body. Your question is much more specific really and the title should reflect it

Comment: I do not agree, but I really appreciate your contribution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Albert if you are talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992400/what-is-a-bare-repository-and-why-would-i-need-one I don't see how accepted answer in the linked duplicate does not answer your question... (Note that second part - searching for examples - is generally off-topic, but since  you already have github as bare repo it is not clear why that example is not enough). Maybe your question is actually about "how web sites render pages that don't exist as files" ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov then it must be me because of my English, that I don't make good questions or I don't understand the answers. I'll try to rephrase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this happens to all of us. At the moment, there is no way to cancel such a flag; the feature was already [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags) in ***2011***, and since April 25th *this year* it finally has been tagged with [status-planned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-planned), so the Stack Exchange team will be doing something about it [(in 6-8 weeks)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).

Otherwise, you shouldn't bother. There are a lot of undeserved flags being cast, that's why we have real humans looking at flags and decide whether they are helpful or not. As long as you keep your percentage of declined flags below 10%, there's no problem for you either.

Comment: Yes, we all have humans and we all make mistakes (and maybe my question is really a duplicate, although I think it's not). Nevertheless, because we are humans only one of us should have such power, or at should least should be a way to revert it. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: This case wasn't about misclicked flags, though, but about a user with a gold badge unilaterally closing the question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, I'm not saying a person with a golden flag can't unilaterally close a question (I think it's not good, but I'm sure it must be a reason for that), I'm just saying in that case, it should be a way to say that I'm not agree. For instance, this question is closed as duplicate by 5 people. The answer those people gave it's not a good answer (it's not even accepted), but I accept because there is a consensus among several people.

Comment: @Albert Give your question a better title and I'll be happy to cast a reopen vote. You need 5 of those to get it reopened.

Comment: @Pekka웃, thanks but it is not necessary, answer given by Glorfindel was good enough for me. I see there is no "standard" mechanism to reopen a question (I already guessed xD), and I just wanted to point that out. With your impressive reputation, you should know that re-edit a question don't usually work, because that question is not queued to be reviewed anywhere.

Comment: @Albert While most closed questions indeed do stay closed, that's not entirely correct: there *is* a mechanism to reopen a question - it takes 5 reopen votes above 3000 points I think - and if a question is voted to reopen, it indeed is put in a review queue and will be seen by other users.

Comment: @Albert I think you misunderstood me - I meant give your question *on Stack Overflow* a better title. The one about bare git repositories. Not the one here.

Comment: @Pekka웃, yes I misunderstood you, I thought you mean here :)

Comment: @Albert not sure how you would know if the question is queued, since you don't have access to the relevant review queue, and I don't think you can see your own posts there until the review is finished anyway.  Editing a question puts it in the reopen queue.  Whether it *gets* reopened is a matter of whether reviewers agree that you have communicated how your question differes from the duplicate.

Comment: @davidism, as far as I know, re-edit only puts in a review queue if you are not the owner of the question, or if your reputation in under 3000. I think I can re-edit my own questions, and that edition does not go into any queue. So, nobody will notice I re-edit my own post and nobody will mark my post to reopen. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Albert you're wrong

Comment: @davidism, ok. If I understood you, when I re-edit my own question, it goes anyway to review queue? Did not know that. Thanks.